# Authorize.net change transaction note in bank account

Tags: transactions, payment-gateway, payment, authorize.net, payment-processing

I already posted in authorize forums and no one was able to tell me. How is it possible to change the note that gets inserted into my bank account from Authorize.net DPM payment? I have several different types of transactions (payments, donations, subscriptions) and my bank account it says "Payment from (company name here) for xxx" What I need it to say is Payment for transaction, payment for donation etc. OR at least "Payment from (company name here) for xxx, trasnsaction id 12345678" so I can at least reference it. I get dozens of transactions but I have no idea what they are from. Anyone have any ideas? I cannot find this documented anywhere. I assume this has to be something common people deal with.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something you can do programmatically or through Authorize.net. This is set by the merchant account provider.